# Android Surfaceview and different resolutions problem

Tags: android, surfaceview, screen-resolution, ondraw

I have encountered a weird problem and I can't manage a way to solve it.

**Scenario**

- I have a Surfaceview on which I draw some images on different positions. First I created folders for l/m/hdip drawables and things worked fine. Then I decided to make only one folder drawable and let Android take care of the sizing. So I deleted the drawable-mdip and drawable-ldip folders, I moved all drawable-hdip contents to drawable folder and run the application.

**Problem**

- When resources were in drawable-hdip the surfaceview handeled the images as supposed to. Everything looked good and in place. After moving the hdip resources to drawable, everything on the surfaceview is oversized, it's like everything is at 130% zoom. I can't find a way to fix this because I can't find a reason why it makes this zoom. The test device is a Galaxy S so it should look good.

Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SurfaceView has problems with resizing images, so the best way for you to solve this problem is to create drawable folders for each resolution you want to target.

Comment: The interesting part is that if I leave the drawable-hdip with resources then the WVGA and HVGA look and work great, but in QVGA the scaling si not done right.

Comment: Cause hdpi devices take resources from the drawable-hdpi folder, and other devices - from default drawable. You should also create a drawable-ldpi folder for QVGA devices.